# How to Hide the UIbarbutton on navigation bar

Tags: iphone

hi i have created a bar button which displays Done when the editing of the text view starts. what actually i need that when i press the done button then the the editable property of textview will become false and the done button hides.

i am done with the first part but how to hide the bar button?

please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@christo16's solution didn't quite work for me, but it lead me to this which worked:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it (it becomes dim):

```
//assuming it's the right one
[[[myNavigationBar topItem]rightBarButtonItem]setEnabled: NO];
```

I think to hide it, you actually have to set it nil.  Then recreate it when you need it.

```
[[myNavigationBar topItem]setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
```

Comment: I think your answer is better; if it's a predefined system button, then they're just floating around as constants anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If it was just a UIButton, I'd say you can do something like this:

```
myButton.hidden = YES;
```

But if it's a UIBarButtonItem, you could try the solution [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/14834-uibarbutton-how-hide-show-one.html). Let us know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Setting it enabled/disabled will not achieve the same as isHidden given that it will still be visible (just slightly dimmer). If you set the bar button item to nil, then you cannot easily toggle it back on again.

Instead, you can toggle visibility on/off by using tint color...here is a Swift implmentation.

Toggle off (simulating `isHidden` true):

```
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
```

And back on (simulating `isHidden` false):

```
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.white // or nil
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.isEnabled = true
```